# Yahoo Mail does not show background image while sending from Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, background-image, yahoo, newsletter

I have an HTML newsletter with background image (repeating).
Since my client is using Outlook 2010, I need to make `*.oft` for the sake of convenience.
Sending the same HTML structure via http://putsmail.com seems to work fine.
Yet it ignores the background image when I try to send my Newsletter via Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure Outlook is downloading images first?
I've just tried this out with an old Outlook template I had and it's working fine.
Sending to Gmail and to Outlook 2010 **from** Outlook 2010 using a .oft

Comment: Well, there are some images in the template. They all show up in the result (i.e Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010), the problem is only with background image and only in Yahoo and Gmail. I am using bullet proof background from http://backgrounds.cm. Since it's working from putsmail, I realized it might be some changes made by outlook on the inserted HTML.